# Mesh not attaching properly to rig with data transfer

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I am creating a character and I want to attach this jacket I made to the rig. When I transfer the weights from the character to the jacket, the jacket’s arms clip through the character.

[image]

pls help im new

Here's the file:
https://blend-exchange.com/b/o08YD0o8

Answer (score 2):

Here is the pose of your armature when I open the file:

[image]

But here is the rest pose:

[image]

As you see the coat shape and the armature pose don't match. You could make the coat match the armature, but as it looks like you want a T pose it would probably be better to do the opposite: Make the armature match the coat, which means giving it a default T pose. To do that, keep the pose you've given to your armature, duplicate the *Armature* modifier of the body, disable the first one, apply the second one, select the armature, switch to *Pose* mode, apply pose as rest pose (see image below), enable the original *Armature* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so so much! Worked like a charm :) Appreciate your quick reply!